# Show/Hide a button after searching in a textbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have a scenario where user first need to search the existing question before adding a new question.

In PowerApps, I have added a text input column with search function. I am looking for a way to show and hide a new question button if the user has searched in the text box.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **hide** the button control if user has searched using text box then use below solution:

Set the **Visible** property of button control to:

```
If(IsBlank(TextBox1.Text), true, false)
```

OR simply:

```
IsBlank(TextBox1.Text)
```

Replace `TextBox1` with the name of your textbox control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you. It will help others with similar question in future.

Comment: You can interchange the place of `true` and `false` if you want to show the button if user has searched using text box.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
Button.Visible = !IsBlank(SearchBox.Text)
```

`!` means `Not` in the formula.

[image]

Reference: [IsBlank.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-isblank-isempty)

Comment: +1 for animation image

Comment: Thank you. It worked!